# How to add already available element in to fieldset of Magento?

Tags: magento

```
$button = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button');
$button->setData(array(
    'label' => $this->__('Some label'),
    'type' => 'submit',
    'class' => 'button'
));
```

I have the above mentioned code which creates a field element.Now I already have the following Fieldset

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array(
                    'legend'       => $helper->__('Connection Settings'),
                    'class'        => 'fieldset-wide'
            ));
```

How do I add the button to the field set.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button', '', array(
    'type'  => 'button',
    'label' => $this->__('Some label'),
    'class' => 'button'
));

$fieldset->addField('my_button', 'note', array(
    'text' => $button->toHtml()
));
```